# Would Draco Malfoy's wand chosen Harry if he had tried it out initially?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

We know Harry is chosen by his Holly and Phoenix feather wand in book one, but what if he had tried out Draco Malfoy's wand initially (when it was still a new wand on the shelf at Ollivanders), would it have chosen him instead? Hawthorn wands are said to be at home with wizards passing through turmoil, and unicorn hair tails are loyal to their owners and not so great with dark arts.

Since Malfoy's wand ends up changing allegiance to Harry after Harry disarms him at Malfoy Manor in the Deathly Hallows, do you think it is plausible that Draco's wand could have been a wand that chose Harry had he tried it out first?

Comment: This seems awfully subjective. We know that Harry would have been able to use it, but there's no way of knowing if it would have chosen him.

Comment: Malfoy's wand only changed allegiance because Harry disarmed him.  This has no relevance to any potential predilection the wand may or may not have had for Harry.

Comment: Only the wands seem to know who they will and won't choose.

Comment: Draco got his letter before Harry, so his wand was probably purchased before Harry's was anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Harry can master Draco’s wand because he disarms him at Malfoy Manor. This doesn’t tell us anything about whether he would have been able to use it, had Ollivander presented it to him on his first visit to the shop.

However, we can guess that Harry probably wouldn’t have been offered the chance. The Pottermore article on wand woods ([transcript](http://archive.today/20130109102909/lady-slytherin-forever.tumblr.com/post/8977740275/wand-woods-off-of-pottermore#selection-413.663-413.850)) has this to say on the subject of hawthorn wands:

> Hawthorn is not easy to master, however, and I would only ever consider placing a hawthorn wand in the hands of a witch or wizard of proven talent, or the consequences might be dangerous.

If this is accurate, then since Harry has yet to have a chance to display any magical talent thus far (having been stuck with the Dursleys for the last ten years), it seems unlikely that Ollivander would have offered him a wand made of hawthorn.

Draco, on the other hand, grew up in a magical family and has probably been doing basic magic since a very young age. He might be offered the hawthorn wand (clearly he was), because he’s already shown some signs of magical ability.

Comment: "then since Harry has yet to have a chance to display any magical talent thus far " Harry made Voldemort disappear (although no one (yet) knows why); I think Ollivander would have offered him a hawthorn wand

Comment: But you must understand that it does not matter if he is proven. Hawthorn wands are best matched with people undergoing turmoil and it is pretty safe to say Harry had been going through a lot of turmoil throughout his life

Comment: @USER920 you both are missing the point. If, in fact, he was offered a hawthorn wand, it WASN'T his match.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that Harry could have used Draco's wand and it have worked for him, but the wand would have not been the best match. This can be seen from the fact that in book 7 Harry used hermione wand and it worked for him, but when he used Draco's it worked better than Hermiones(because he had won it), but it still didn't work as well as his first wand.

> "Harry looked down at the hawthorn wand that had once belonged to
>   Draco Malfoy. He had been surprised, but pleased, to discover that it
>   worked for him at least as well as Hermione's had done." —Harry
>   Potter    http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Draco_Malfoy%27s_wand

Remember his wand is special since only 2 like it were made.

> "The wand chooses the wizard... it's not always clear why."
>   —Ollivander talking to Harry Potter
>   http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wand

We can't really say why the wand chooses the wizard as said by ollivander in that qoute. This qoute came from the Harry Potter wikia.

Also his wand was special, since he was Harry Potter the boy who lived his wand going to probably be related to Voldemort's wand. Since Draco's wasn't related it isn't likely that Harry would have gotten it.

His connection to his wand can be seen from this qoute from the Harry Potter wikia.

> He had tried out many other wands first with little success, but felt
>   a warm feeling upon being handed the holly wand.[1] Despite his wand
>   being brothers with Lord Voldemort's wand, noted by Ollivander after
>   Harry's wand had been chosen, Harry generally did not put much thought
>   into this connection at first, regarding the relationship as something
>   that the wand could not help, any more than he could help being
>   related to his aunt.     http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter's_wand

So all in all as long as he was Harry Potter there would have been no change in wand since his wand was given to him because of the connection Harry and Voldemort shared. Remeber the shared cores of Fawkes feathers.

These qoutes from the wikia should help you see that he would never got Draco's wand.

> "Wands are only as powerful as the wizards who use them...." —Hermione
>   explaining to Harry Potter[src]
>
> ...... In almost all documented cases the
>   wand chooses the wizard who matches its character because the wizard
>   may have difficulty or be unable to perform magic if his or her wand's
>   characters conflict, or the magic may be sub-par to magic performed
>   with a matching wand. Although Ollivander says that wizardkind can
>   channel their powers through almost anything, optimum results can only
>   be achieved with those they have a natural affinity for. When trying
>   out different wands, a wand that is not suited to its wielder will
>   usually not do anything at all. However, a warm feeling is an
>   indication of having chosen the right wand, and the wand sometimes
>   emits a few sparks or does some similar, small sign of
>   magic.http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wand
>
> Wands can take new masters. When a wand's master is disarmed, stunned,
>   or killed, the wand may accept the old master's attacker as its new
>   master, swaying its allegiance over to the wizard who won it from its
>   preceding owner. This phenomena is mostly observed in the Elder Wand,
>   which, according to Albus Dumbledore, only respects power. The Elder
>   Wand will transfer its allegiance even if its defeated master is not
>   in possession of it at the time. No other wand is known to share this
>   trait.[3] Most wands are attached to their masters and will not easily
>   discontinue their allegiance with the previous master, if at all.
>   Indeed the original bond seems unlikely to be severed; if it were,
>   then a defeated witch or wizard would be better served to acquire a
>   new wand rather than continue using it because it would no longer
>   perform at its peak for them--yet they don't. Furthermore, wands
>   forcibly taken in circumstances of purely competitive or friendly
>   nature or stolen without attacking the previous master will not change
>   allegiance.http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wand

We can see that Draco's wand did pick him and only him in the qoute from the Harry Potter wikia and book 7.

> Draco: "You have something of mine. I'd like it back." Harry: "What's
>   wrong with the one you have?" Draco: "It's my mother's. It's powerful
>   but, it's not the same... doesn't quite, understand me. Know what I
>   mean?" — Draco asking Harry for his wand
>   back.http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Draco_Malfoy%27s_wand

Also the size of his wand might make a difference. This is from the wikia, so you might say its conjecture, but the wikia is somewhat(usually) accurate.

Malfoy's wand-

> Draco Malfoy's wand - Hawthorn, unicorn hair, 10 inches.

Harry's wand-

> > was 11 inches long, made of holly and had a phoenix feather core Because numbers have known magical properties, a wand's length, much
> >     like its core, may symbolize something its owner. For example, the
> >     wand of Tom Riddle, a reputed Dark wizard, measures 13½ inches, and
> >     thirteen is commonly an omen of misfortune or evil in the folklore and
> >     religion of various cultures around the world. Wands that are
> >     unusually short, anything less than 9", tend to belong to people
> >     "lacking" in personalities, Dolores Umbridge being a known
> >     example.http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wand

This information gotten the wikia seems to prove that Harry could have used Draco's wand. But it would never have picked him.

Comment: Good answer and description.

Comment: “The Wikia is very accurate.” Debatable.

Comment: The Wikia is awfully inaccurate, with narrative descriptions designed to talk around nuggets of canon fact that don't actually have full support in canon. (or if they do, lacking cites/references)